# Why is this seemingly more complicated function faster at changing the date?

Tags: javascript

I have these two functions to modify dates, once I use only to decrease and one that can increase or decrease the date by one day depending on the input.

These are the functions:

```js
//function 1, marked slower by sites like jsbench but seems way more simple: 

function inc_date (date, inc_dec) {
        //increases date by daily
        var tomorrow = new Date(date);


  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + inc_dec);

  return(tomorrow.toISOString())
    }
 console.log((inc_date("2023-01-01", -1)).split(" ")[0])
      
      
 //function 2, marked faster but only decreases date:
 
       function decr_date(date_str){
        var parts = date_str.split("-");
        var dt = new Date(
          parseInt(parts[0], 10),      // year
          parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,  // month (starts with 0)
          parseInt(parts[2], 10)       // date
        );
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        parts[0] = "" + dt.getFullYear();
        parts[1] = "" + (dt.getMonth() + 1);
        if (parts[1].length < 2) {
          parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
        }
        parts[2] = "" + dt.getDate();
        if (parts[2].length < 2) {
          parts[2] = "0" + parts[2];
        }
        return parts.join("-");
      }
console.log(decr_date("2023-01-01"))
```

The second function seems far more complicated to me, but benchmark sites show it's faster so I was wondering why that is?

Comment: Basically because the first one tries to infer the format and does a lot more work trying to do that. The other methods knows exactly what format the date has and parses that. Code length / visual complexity has nothing to do with runtime.

Answer (score 0):

this works too :

```js
let date = null;
function num2(n){
        var toStr = n.toString();
        var formatTwo = toStr.padStart(2,"0");
        
        return formatTwo;
}
function changeDateByDay(date,difference){
        var someDate = date;
        someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate()+difference);
        let YYYY = someDate.getFullYear()
        let MM = num2(someDate.getMonth()+1)
        let DD = num2(someDate.getDate());
        return(YYYY +"-" + MM +"-" + DD + " diff = " + difference);
    }
//USAGE
date = new Date(2023,0,1);
console.log("today = " + changeDateByDay(date,0));
date = new Date(2023,0,1);
console.log("yesterday = " + changeDateByDay(date,-1));
date = new Date(2023,0,1);
console.log("tomorrow = " + changeDateByDay(date,+1));
```

Comment: So? The question was not to get alternative solutions.

Comment: Ooops, a misunderstanding so! @luk2302